# Ruby - undefined method sort for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am stumped by this:

I am trying to sort an array in my controller like so:

## controller

```
@sorted = sort_by_reviews(@search, "count")
```

## model

```
def self.sort_by_reviews(array, type)
if type == "count"
  array.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.count <=> x.reviews.count }
else
  array.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.average.to_f <=> x.reviews.average.to_f }
end
```

end

However, I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `sort_by_reviews' for #<BuildingsController:0x007f80d89be320>
```

What is confusing is that when I just do this in my controller:

```
@sorted = @search.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.count <=> x.reviews.count }
```

It works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

---Update

My full controller code:

```
@search = Model.search_attributes(params[:search])
@sorted = @search.sort_by_reviews "count"
```

My adjusted model method:

```
def sort_by_reviews(type)
if type == "count"
   self.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.count <=> x.reviews.count }
 else
   self.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.average.to_f <=> x.reviews.average.to_f }
 end
end
```

I still get the same error:

```
undefined method `sort_by_reviews' for #<Array:0x007f80d423ee50>
```

Comment: Do you really have a model called `Model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```
@sorted = sort_by_reviews(@search, "count")
```

Model:

```
def self.sort_by_reviews(array, type)
if type == "count"
  array.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.count <=> x.reviews.count }
else
  array.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.average.to_f <=> x.reviews.average.to_f }
end
```

In the model, you are using a class method. So, in the controller you just call it like this:

```
@sorted = ModelName.sort_by_reviews(@search, "count")
```

For example, your model name is `Foo`, which means:

```
@sorted = Foo.sort_by_reviews(@search, "count")
```

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `sort_by_reviews` as a class method on the model but calling it as an instance method on the controller.  I'd have to see more of the code to have a recommendation for how to proceed, but maybe change the model to:

```
def sort_by_reviews(type)
  if type == "count"
    self.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.count <=> x.reviews.count }
  else
    self.sort! { |x, y| y.reviews.average.to_f <=> x.reviews.average.to_f }
  end
end
```

and the controller to

```
@sorted = @search.sort_by_reviews "count"
```

Comment: Please see my update. I changed the code as you suggested (and had it like this before) but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Oh, I see, `@search` is an array of `Model`s.  That wasn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

While Rajendran's answer works, I really don't like this structure.  You are implementing a method on the Model class that sorts an array in place based on a parameter.  The interesting and reusable piece of code is the part that takes to objects of the Model class and compares them.  That code should be extracted so that it can be used anywhere Model objects need to be compared.

Something like this:

```
class Model
  def self.compare_by_reviews_count_desc(x,y)  # Descending order of review count
    y.reviews.count <=> x.reviews.count
  end

  def self.compare_by_reviews_average_desc(x,y) # Descending order of review average
    y.reviews.average.to_f <=> x.reviews.average.to_f
  end

  # These functions return method objects for use in other functions
  def self.reviews_count_desc_sorter  
    method(:compare_by_reviews_count_desc)
  end

  def self.reviews_average_desc_sorter
    method(:compare_by_reviews_average_desc)
  end
end
```

Then in your Controller, since `@search` is an array of Models, instead of

```
@sorted = sort_by_reviews(@search, "count")
```

you would have

```
@sorted = @search.sort &Model.reviews_count_desc_sorter
```

Then if you wanted to sort by average review, you would have

```
@sorted = @search.sort &Model.reviews_average_desc_sorter
```

It is a little more verbose, but now you have the ability to `sort` or `sort!` and the details of what kind of collection you are sorting are not embedded in the Model, while the details of how to do the comparison remain encapsulated in the Model.